# Login doesn't work on heroku for my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, devise

I'm using devise for authentication. It works fine locally, but on heroku when I try to login or sign up I get an error.

Here's the heroku logs. I had to cut a lot of it out, because the apparently it's too much code to post -_-. I can post up more if needed. Thanks in advance!

```
    2015-01-21T08:46:21.690491+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:733:in `column_definitions'
2015-01-21T08:46:21.690522+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
2015-01-21T08:46:21.690534+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
2015-01-21T08:46:21.690548+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-
2015-01-21T08:46:21.690505+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:7:in `new'
2015-01-21T08:46:21.690519+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
2015-01-21T08:46:21.690531+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
2015-01-21T08:46:21.690541+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
2015-01-21T08:46:21.690556+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
2015-01-21T08:46:21.690569+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
2015-01-21T08:46:21.690579+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
2015-01-21T08:46:21.690594+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
2015-01-21T08:46:21.690603+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:647:in `call'
2015-01-21T08:46:21.690635+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2015-01-21T08:46:21.690648+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
2015-01-21T08:46:21.688700+00:00 app[web.1]: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
2015-01-21T08:46:21.688715+00:00 app[web.1]:                  AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
2015-01-21T08:46:21.690463+00:00 app[web.1]: :               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),

2015-01-21T08:46:21.690649+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
2015-01-21T08:46:21.690652+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
2015-01-21T08:46:21.690656+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in `service'
2015-01-21T08:46:21.921094+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=murmuring-coast-6346.herokuapp.com request_id=4e931974-f7bf-429d-8659-98f3c016fd8d fwd="67.164.93.44" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=133
2015-01-21T08:46:21.695443+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/users/sign_up" host=murmuring-coast-6346.herokuapp.com request_id=a148b692-c0a6-4998-8710-3a919b0c1025 fwd="67.164.93.44" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=12ms status=500 bytes=1754
```

**Gemfile**

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
group :development, :test do 
    gem 'sqlite3'
end

gem 'devise'

gem 'cancan'

gem 'pg'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

gem 'paperclip'



group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'



  ruby '2.2.0'

end


gem 'mocha', group: :test
```

Comment: Did you run migration on heroku environment (`heroku run bundle exec rake db:migrate`)?

Comment: try `rake db:migrate` seems like your tables are missing

Comment: It seems like you have no users table on heroku. So for that as per above comments you need to do `rake db:migrate`   and then you need to try it.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to run heroku run rake db:migrate!